# twitter bootstrap and codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm want to create an autosuggest field using twitter bootstraps typeahead plugin. here is my current code. It returns 500 Internal Server Error in inspect elements console. I think the problem is in model. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

### view: register

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#office').typeahead({
            source: function(typeahead, query) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('main/get_offices'); ?>",
                    type: "post",
                    data: "search=" + query,
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        typeahead.process(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

### controller: main

```
public function get_offices() {
    $this->load->model('offices');

    $data = $this->offices->get();

    echo json_encode($data);
```

### }

### model: offices

```
public function get() {
    $office = $this->input->post('search');

    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('departments');
    $this->db->like('name', $office);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $office_array = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $office_array = $row->name;
    }
    //$data['office'] = $office_array;

    return $office_array;
}
```

Comment: yo dawg check your server error log.  I rhymed on purpose

Comment: there's nothing in there. all logs seen are from past

Comment: ok. the 500 error is gone. and still no return result from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with typeahead in the function parameters but that doesn't seem supported.
I rewrote your code to remove typeahead and return the result outside the scope of the ajax call.

```
$('#office').typeahead({
  source: function(query) {
    var result = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('main/get_offices'); ?>",
      type: "post",
      data: "search=" + query,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data); // verify that you actually get data from the model
        result = data;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

The model function get seems to have a typo, at this part

```
$office_array = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $office_array = $row->name;
}
```

It should be `$office_array[]`.

```
$office_array = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $office_array[] = $row->name;
}
```

Comment: I already figure it out. I just can't post the answer since im less than 10 repu..thanks anyway for giving time to this.